# Joining multiple tables with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to convert this query to a LINQ query:

```
select proj.CustomerName, proj.projectid, ProjectNumber, oe.FullName, oe.Rate, oe.jobid, opj.BillRate, hours.Hours, hours.WeekStart 
    from RMT_TaskEmployeeHours hours

        join OracleEmployees oe
        on hours.EmployeeNumber = oe.EmployeeNumber

            join OracleProjectTasks tasks
            on hours.TaskId = tasks.TaskID

                join OracleProjects proj
                on tasks.ProjectID = proj.ProjectID

                    left join OracleProjectJobs opj
                    on opj.ProjectID = proj.ProjectID
                    and oe.jobid = opj.JobID
                    where oe.Office  like '%san francisco%'
                    and opj.EndDate is null
                    and WeekStart > '2015-1-22' and WeekStart < '2015-2-19'
```

I got stuck after writing:

```
var test = db.RMT_TaskEmployeeHours.
                   Join(
                       db.OracleEmployees,
                       hours => hours.EmployeeNumber,
                       oe => oe.EmployeeNumber,
                       (hours, oe) => new {hours, oe}).
                   Join(
                        db.OracleProjectTasks,
                        oh => oh.oe.
                   ).
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add more detail to your question please? We don't know what your data or schema look like.

Comment: What type of LINQ? And please show the classes with navigation properties. Joining by LINQ syntax is hardly ever necessary.

Comment: What, specifically don't you know how to do?  Which piece of the query are you struggling to translate into LINQ?

Comment: left join OracleProjectJobs opj
                    on opj.ProjectID = proj.ProjectID
                    and oe.jobid = opj.JobID
                    where oe.Office  like '%san francisco%'
                    and opj.EndDate is null
                    and WeekStart > '2015-1-22' and WeekStart < '2015-2-19'

Comment: You really should put some more effort in following up on comments. Most comments are from people really trying to help but just asking for clarification in order to give the best answer possible. You just repeated a part of your question as a response to Servy's comment. You didn't tell anything about navigation properties, while they are absolutely essential here. Maybe you don't know what navigation properties are? Well, feel free to ask. Take your chance while people are still around. Questions sink into oblivion quickly here.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try http://www.sqltolinq.com/.

Try looking up tutorials on `Linqer`.  This will help you get started on writing SQL to LINQ.